# Using LowDB on Electron APP

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, gulp, electron

I'm developing a basic app made with Electron and AngularJS. For this purpose I'm using the electron boilerplate (https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate) and for database, I'm using LowDB(https://github.com/typicode/lowdb).

I have been able to create a database(JSON) and read it from a script. But my problem is when I want to update and save. I can update, and the change is reflected on the JSON file, but when I start the app again, the JSON has the same data that at the beginning (it is overwritten).

I think it is a problem with the build task of Electron boilerplate, that always overwrites the file. I thought that when I did the task to release the app, it will fixes(npm run release), but not, it overwrites the json.

I am loading the database so:

```
import low from 'lowdb';
import storage from 'lowdb/file-sync';
import {
    remote
}
from 'electron';
var fs = require('fs');

var app = remote.require('app');

const db = low(__dirname + '/db.json', {
    storage
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

db('users').push({
    'name': 'foo'
});

});
```

This script is loaded at the beginning, so it should add, every time that app is started, a new entry. The script is writting the new entry in JSON file but when the start is restarted, the JSON back to the previous state.

At the end, I am using the localStorage, but I would like to use LowDB to save the data locally.

Here is the task (gulp file) that I commented before about the build of app:

```
'use strict';

var pathUtil = require('path');
var Q = require('q');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var batch = require('gulp-batch');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var jetpack = require('fs-jetpack');

var bundle = require('./bundle');
var generateSpecImportsFile = require('./generate_spec_imports');
var utils = require('../utils');

var projectDir = jetpack;
var srcDir = projectDir.cwd('./app');
var destDir = projectDir.cwd('./build');

var paths = {
    copyFromAppDir: [
        './node_modules/**',
        './bower_components/**',
        './components/**',
        './scripts/**',
        './shared.services/**',
        './sections/**',
        './helpers/**',
        './db.json',
        './**/*.html',
        './**/*.+(jpg|png|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)'
    ],
}

// -------------------------------------
// Tasks
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('sass', ['clean'], function() {
    console.log('Compiling SASS...');
    gulp.src('app/styles/scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destDir.path('styles')));
});

gulp.task('watch:sass', function() {
    console.log('Watching SASS...');
    var sassWatcher = gulp.watch(['app/styles/scss/*.scss','app/**/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);

    sassWatcher.on('change', function(event) {
        console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
    });
gulp.src('app/styles/scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destDir.path('styles')));
});


gulp.task('clean', function (callback) {
    return destDir.dirAsync('.', { empty: true });
});


var copyTask = function () {
    return projectDir.copyAsync('app', destDir.path(), {
            overwrite: true,
            matching: paths.copyFromAppDir
        });
};
gulp.task('copy', ['clean'], copyTask);
gulp.task('copy-watch', copyTask);


var bundleApplication = function () {
    return Q.all([
            bundle(srcDir.path('background.js'), destDir.path('background.js')),
            bundle(srcDir.path('app.js'), destDir.path('app.js')),
            bundle(srcDir.path('script.js'), destDir.path('script.js')),
        ]);
};

var bundleSpecs = function () {
    return generateSpecImportsFile().then(function (specEntryPointPath) {
        return bundle(specEntryPointPath, destDir.path('spec.js'));
    });
};

var bundleTask = function () {
    if (utils.getEnvName() === 'test') {
        return bundleSpecs();
    }
    return bundleApplication();
};
gulp.task('bundle', ['clean'], bundleTask);
gulp.task('bundle-watch', bundleTask);




gulp.task('finalize', ['clean'], function () {
    var manifest = srcDir.read('package.json', 'json');

    // Add "dev" or "test" suffix to name, so Electron will write all data
    // like cookies and localStorage in separate places for each environment.
    switch (utils.getEnvName()) {
        case 'development':
            manifest.name += '-dev';
            manifest.productName += ' Dev';
            break;
        case 'test':
            manifest.name += '-test';
            manifest.productName += ' Test';
            break;
    }

    // Copy environment variables to package.json file for easy use
    // in the running application. This is not official way of doing
    // things, but also isn't prohibited ;)
    manifest.env = projectDir.read('config/env_' + utils.getEnvName() + '.json', 'json');

    destDir.write('package.json', manifest);
});


gulp.task('watch', function () {
    watch('app/**/*.js', batch(function (events, done) {
        gulp.start('bundle-watch', done);
    }));
    watch(paths.copyFromAppDir, { cwd: 'app' }, batch(function (events, done) {
        gulp.start('copy-watch', done);
    }));
    watch('app/**/scss/*.scss', batch(function (events, done) {
        gulp.start('watch:sass', done);
    }));
    watch('app/**/**/*.scss', batch(function (events, done) {
        gulp.start('watch:sass');
    }));
});


gulp.task('build', ['bundle', 'sass', 'copy', 'finalize']);
```

How you can see, in 'copyFromAppDir' there is a db.json. This file is my database, but I want update it and changes persist, but I am not be able to do that.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your gulp task 'clean' is overwriting your db.json file. Because you are using lowDB, this is the same as overwriting your database. If you remove the line `'./db.json',` from the 'copyFromAppDir' array the changes should persist.

Like this:

```
var paths = {
    copyFromAppDir: [
        './node_modules/**',
        './bower_components/**',
        './components/**',
        './scripts/**',
        './shared.services/**',
        './sections/**',
        './helpers/**',
        './**/*.html',
        './**/*.+(jpg|png|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)'
    ],
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Josh, but If I remove the db.json from there, the task which build the app cannot locate the db.json and then, it will be empty. I could fill it, but when start the app, again it won't locate the file and will create a new one, but empty